# Percentage change based on two numbers, total unknown (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database containing regular price and discount price. I'm trying to calculate the percentage change from the highest of these numbers to the current lowest number.

The percentages are incorrect when the regular price is lower than the discount price.

Code:

```
SELECT brand_price, brand_discount_price,
((brand_discount_price - brand_price)/brand_price) * 100 as percentage
FROM brand
```

How can i adapt the calculation to take into account which one is the current "total"?

I guess i need to either change the calculation or conditionally compare the two numbers for highest/lowest and change the SELECT dynamically? Any ideas?

Sample data:

```
brand_price     brand_discount_price percentage
8.7451          9.3345              6.73977427%
7.9537          7.9538              0.00125728%
4.5832          2.2482              -50.94693664%
3.2331          11.8412             266.24911076%
```

Example:

brand price 50
discount price 100

(100 - 50/50) * 100 = 100% change

brand price 100
discount price 50

(50 - 100/50) * 100 = -100% change = wrong(?)

Basicallys, its due to the way the calculation is done since i coulnd't figure out how to insert the bigger number as total (i think, percentages are not something im good at).

Comment: some sample data maybe ??

Comment: Some sample data with what you're getting and what you expect...

Comment: what is your wished result to be ?

Comment: pecentage of what ? , what do u mean with percentage ? the percentage of the discount prices in total price or the opposite ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use an if(though I am not quite sure why would the regular price ever be lower than the discount one):

```
SELECT brand_price, brand_discount_price,
IF(brand_discount_price > brand_price, ((brand_discount_price - brand_price)/brand_discount_price) * 100, ((brand_price - brand_discount_price)/brand_price)*100)  as percentage
FROM brand
```

Comment: It shouldn't, although i guess it could happen temporarily or possibly if i compare an all-time low price with a new discount price. I would need the solution either way even if the example is somehow... strange :) Thank you for the input. I'll try it out.

Comment: @raecer please note I have done a change to reflect the percentage of the higher price that is the discount. You seemed to have an error there in  the original post.

Answer (score 2):

i see that you have problem with the price and discount price and percentage also,

here an example :

```
      $15.00      original price   
     - 1.50       - discount       // here the discount should be lower then original price.
      $13.50       sale price
```

and the percentage i guess in your query you wish to get the percentage of the discount amount from the original price .so it will be like that

```
     SELECT round(brand_price,4) as price, round(brand_discount_price,4) as discount,
     if(brand_discount_price < brand_price,
     round((( brand_discount_price ) * 100) / brand_price , 2), 'discount chould be   less then the original price') as percentage
      FROM `brand`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce21e/7)